Dovecot error when trying to access mailbox
I can't get DoveCot functioning on one domain out of several domains and users. All others work perfectly. When trying to connect to this user's mailbox I get a server error "Internal error occurred." and found the following messages in the system mail log:
Apr 14 08:57:30 server dovecot[902917]: imap(@<domain.com>)<908694>: Error: chdir(/home/<unix_user>/imap/<domain.com>//) failed: Permission denied (euid=1004(somename) egid=12(mail) missing +x perm: /home/<unix_user>, we're not in group 1001(access), dir owned by 1007:1001 mode=0710)
I created the Unix users, domains and mailboxes with DirectAdmin.
I already tried $ sh /usr/local/directadmin/scripts/set_permissions.sh all (run as root) to no avail.
And I compared all permissions of all mail related files (/home/<unix_user>/imap/... and /etc/virtual/...) with another user for which everything works. No differences found there.
I'm on Almalinux 8.9 with DirectAdmin 1.661.
Any suggestions how I should find the cause of this?

I don't know how dovecot installation works, which users it uses for its normal operations, so be aware that the changes suggested below may have security consequences or may break your server.

failed: Permission denied (euid=1004(somename) egid=12(mail) missing +x perm: /home/<unix_user>, we're not in group 1001(access), dir owned by 1007:1001 mode=0710)

So, user 1004:12 (somename:mail) tries to chdir to /home/<unix_user> that belongs to 1007:1001.
Why is somename (1004) not the same as unix_user (1007) is a mystery to me. But if this is correct you have 2 solutions.
Either change group ownership of /home/<unix_user> to mail (12) or make somename a member of the access (1001) group. The latter seems the thing to do as “we're not in group 1001(access)” suggests that we should be in that group.
usermod -a -G access somename

You may have to restart dovecot, or reboot your mail server.


And I compared all permissions of all mail related files (/home/<unix_user>/imap/... and /etc/virtual/...) with another user for which everything works. No differences found there.

The error message only mentions /home/unix_user not /home/unix_user/imap. Checking imap is irrelevant.

Thanks @exore, you've really put me on the right track:
Why is somename (1004) not the same as unix_user (1007) is a mystery to me.
I found in the /etc/virtual/<unix_user>/passwd file a reference to that damned 1004 and changed it to 1007. Now it's all working.  Don't know why there was a wrong userid in that file. Somebody must have messed it up (probably stupid me...). Thanks again and have a nice day!
